# Dividend impact on accumulating inverse ETFs

Tags: etf, dividends, shorting-securities, dividend-reinvestment

This is a pretty straightforward clarification question. For inverse ETFs tracking an index which are tagged as "accumulating", what this actually means is that we are not tracking the inverse **price** return of the index, but rather its **total** return. Is this correct?